# Circulant Graph Definition

Tags: graph-theory

Question: If a circulant graph has $k$ vertices where k is odd and greater than 1, show that there are atleast $2k$ automorphisms?

I am having trouble with the actual definition of circulant graphs. Given these n vertices, how do I know which vertices are adjacent or not. Also how would I go about doing this proof?

Comment: There are several (equivalent) ways to define *circulant graph*; which are you using?

Comment: Let C be a subset of the integers modulo n such that 0 is not in C and if a is in C then -a is in C. The circulant with connection set C has the integers modulo n as vertices where i is adjacent to j iff j-i is in C.

Comment: I’d have to think about the argument, but to get you started thinking about what such graphs are like, here are a couple of simple examples. If $C=\{1,-1\}$, you just get an $n$-cycle. If $n$ is even and $C=\{n/2\}$, you just get $n/2$ copies of $K_2$. You can take a look at the pictures [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CirculantGraph.html) to see more examples.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I get the general idea of the graphs now but I am still quite confused about how I can make a proof out of this definition.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Prove that any rotation and any reflection is an automorphism of your graph.